# Set a group of input fields to be disabled if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

I'm trying to write a wordpress widget but the options form is giving me some grief. The widget is designed to show an two images and a counter beneath each where the counter relies on the date. That logic is sorted.

However in a case where there is to be no counter on an image, i'm trying to put a checkbox which when checked will disable the input fields dealing with the image and counter so i can jsut read a boolean and output a simpler image with no counter.

The problem I'm having is that the JQuery that's attached to the checkbox is disabling the inputs, but i can't click it again to enable them as it just locks in its state of limbo as the checkbox gains a blue 'glow' and doesn't look checked. I don't get why the code isn't working as i expect. It's worth noting that this is my first time using JQuery, and the solution doesn't need to be JQuery if standard javascript can do the same.

I have 2 sections which will be identical in functionality, one for each image-counter pair. this is  the code for one of those sections:

```
<h3>Anime 1</h3>
    <p>
        <input class="check1" type="checkbox" <?php checked($instance['s1rand'], 'on'); ?> id="rand1" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1rand'); ?>" /> 
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('s1rand'); ?>">Label of your checkbox variable</label>
    </p>
<div class="ani1">
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('s1title'); ?>"><?php _e('Anime 1 Name:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('s1title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $s1title; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('s1date'); ?>"><?php _e('Anime 1 Start Date:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('s1date'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1date'); ?>" type="date" value="<?php echo $s1date; ?>" />
</p>
</div>
```

The JQuery

```
jQuery(function($){

  $(document).on('click', '#rand1', function(evt){
    checked = $('#rand1').val();
    $('div.ani1 :input').attr('disabled',checked);
    return false;
  });
});
```

EDIT: Since posting i have altered the code so that i now work with ids rather than classes, but the problem persists, even when using 3rror404's solution

New code:

```
<h3>Anime 1</h3>
<p>
    <input class="check1" type="checkbox" <?php checked($instance['s1rand'], 'on'); ?> id="rand1" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1rand'); ?>" /> 
    <label for="rand1">Label of your checkbox variable</label>
</p>
<div id="ani1">
<p>
    <label for="s1title"><?php _e('Anime 1 Name:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="s1title" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $s1title; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="s1date"><?php _e('Anime 1 Start Date:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="s1date" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('s1date'); ?>" type="date" value="<?php echo $s1date; ?>" />
</p>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#rand1').on('change',function() {
  var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked'); // this will equate to either 'true' or 'false'...
  alert(isChecked); //this line doesn't work, which makes me think this function isn't working
  $('#ani1 input').attr('disabled',isChecked); // ...meaning that we can use its value to set the 'disabled' attribute 
});
```

I'm running JQuery version 1.11.1 according to the following statement:

```
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

Comment: If `alert(isChecked);` doesn't work then the change event isn't firing. Are you sure `rand1` is the correct `ID`? what is alerted if you add `alert($('#rand1').length)` to your document ready block?

Comment: I'm sure it's the right id. alert($('#rand1').length) outputs 1 - what does that mean in context, as i can't think what a checkbox's length would be.

Comment: length refers to the size of the array of elements return by your selector. So the element definitely exists. Are you wrapping the above code in a jquery "document ready" block?

Comment: assuming jQuery(function ($) { code } is a document ready block, yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all of the inputs within `.ani1` to be disabled if `#rand1` is checked and enabled if not checked(?). So this should work:

```js
$('#rand1').on('change',function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked'); // this will equate to either 'true' or 'false'...
    $('div.ani1 input').attr('disabled',isChecked); // ...meaning that we can use its value to set the 'disabled' attribute 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Anime 1</h3>
    <p>
        <input class="check1" type="checkbox" id="rand1" name="" /> 
        <label for="rand1">Label of your checkbox variable</label>
    </p>
<div class="ani1">
<p>
    <label for="input1">label</label>
    <input class="widefat" id="input1" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
    <label for="input2"></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="input2" type="date" />
</p>

...
    
</div>
```

Comment: I see that code working in the example, but it doesn't seem to work on my options page.
The checkbox is now properly checkable, but it doesn't disable them now.

Comment: Which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: No idea, whatever is installed with wordpress when you install the version of webmatrix that comes with it

Comment: Open your browsers dev tools and check. Also check for errors in the console whilst your at it

Comment: Just made an edit, added jquery version and debug statements. No errors on Chrome's console.